# Implement Google account auth in Glass using GDK

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I was exploring Google Glass where I need to create events/reminders. To achieve this I need to use [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/). But to use the same I'm required to pass the users Google Account authentication. One option would be using Mirror API like other app does. But to use mirror API I need to write server-side code, which I do not want to do.

So anyone could please help me out that how could I authenticate user in app using only GDK.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment this isn't possible. Google Play Services aren't support on Google Glass as of update XE12.

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/authentication might help now. Though service auth part is not explained well enough.